# Drawer functionality in android just like paytm

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, categories, navigation-drawer, paytm

I want to implement drawer functionality in my android application just like flipkart can anyone help how to show subcategories in the same drawer on the click of respected category

Comment: check my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Expandable listview in drawer like this

https://github.com/msahakyan/expandable-navigation-drawer

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;

    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
    private List<String> mExpandableListTitle;
    private Map<String, List<String>> mExpandableListData;
    private TextView mSelectedItemView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mSelectedItemView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_item);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null, false);
        mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

        mExpandableListData = ExpandableListDataSource.getData(this);
        mExpandableListTitle = new ArrayList(mExpandableListData.keySet());

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        mExpandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, mExpandableListTitle, mExpandableListData);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString());
                mSelectedItemView.setText(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString());
            }
        });

        mExpandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.film_genres);
                mSelectedItemView.setText(R.string.selected_item);
            }
        });

        mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String selectedItem = ((List) (mExpandableListData.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))))
                    .get(childPosition).toString();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedItem);
                mSelectedItemView.setText(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString() + " -> " + selectedItem);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.film_genres);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have another issue you can post new question, you should not ask here..and accept this answer if it helped you

Comment: glad to help you,happy coding :)

Comment: Got the solution... done it by using recyclerview... but thanx for telling a  new thing...